# Count frequency of item in tuple with kwargs**

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

This is what I wrote:

```
def count_passes(**kwargs)
    count = 0 #Complete this function to count the number of passes
    for pas in kwargs:
        if pas == mark:
            count = count + 1
        return 

result = count_passes(math="Fail", science="Fail", history="Pass", english="Pass") 
print(f'The number of passes: {count_occurrence(result, "Pass")}')
```

How do I make it to count how often 'Pass' is in `kwargs`?

Comment: Does count_passes actually work properly? Variable mark is inherited from global scope, so its content is unknown. Also return will be executed on every first iteration of the loop resulting in None value, for the variable it's assigned to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing some code from the question, but here is how you can do the count:

```
def count_occurrences(mark, **kwargs):
    count = 0  # Complete this function to count the number of passes
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if value == mark:
            print(f"Passed {key}")
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

`kwargs` is a `dict` so you need to address it's `items()` or `values()` when iterating. Otherwise you're just going through the keywords. Also the return statement should be after the loop and actually return the count as a value.

In case you wanted to improve on the implementation, here is a lighter way to do the same thing:

```
def count_occurrences_simpler(mark, **kwargs):
    return sum(1 for v in kwargs.values() if v == mark)
```

Then just call the function and print the result like you were doing

```
result = count_occurrences("Pass", math="Fail", science="Fail", history="Pass", english="Pass")
print(f'The number of passes: {result}')
```

Answer (score 0):

`kwargs` is a dictionary of values:

```py
{"math":"Fail", "science":"Fail", "history":"Pass", "english":"Pass"}
```

in your example.
When you iterate over that dictionary, your are only getting the keys: `"math"`, `"science"`, etc.

To get the value associated with that key, you need to get it from the original dict: `kwargs[pas]` in your case.

Also, notice that in your code, you are not returning any value, so you are dropping all the work your function is doing to compute `count`.
Finally, you are returning in your `for` loop, right after you've started it, so you need to return at the end of the loop

However, in your case you can use `kwargs.items()` to get both the key and the values for instance, or even `kwargs.values()`, since you don't actually use the key in your code:

```py
mark = "Pass"
def count_passes(**kwargs)
    count = 0 #Complete this function to count the number of passes
    for pas in kwargs.values():
        if pas == mark:
            count = count + 1
    return count

result = count_passes(math="Fail", science="Fail", history="Pass", english="Pass") 

print(f'The number of passes: {count_occurrence(result, "Pass")}')
```

Answer (score 0):

`kwargs` is a dictionary, so you need to check the values. One option is to convert the values to a `list` and use the `count` function

```
def count_passes(**kwargs):
    return list(kwargs.values()).count('Pass')
```